# Apache rewrite rule doesn't match in ".htaccess" file

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

The same Apache rewrite rule works (match) in VHost but not in ".htaccess" file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 192.168.1.100
ServerAlias example.com
DocumentRoot /test

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/test.html$ /test2.html
RewriteLog "/tmp/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9

<Directory "/">
AllowOverride All
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Rewrite Log:

```
192.168.1.10 - - [13/May/2013:16:19:31 +0100] [example.com/sid#7fd764555ed0][rid#7fd764ad9758/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /test.html
192.168.1.10 - - [13/May/2013:16:19:31 +0100] [example.com/sid#7fd764555ed0][rid#7fd764ad9758/initial] (3) applying pattern '^/test.html$' to uri '/test.html'
192.168.1.10 - - [13/May/2013:16:19:31 +0100] [example.com/sid#7fd764555ed0][rid#7fd764ad9758/initial] (2) rewrite '/test.html' -> '/test2.html'
192.168.1.10 - - [13/May/2013:16:19:31 +0100] [example.com/sid#7fd764555ed0][rid#7fd764ad9758/initial] (2) local path result: /test2.html
192.168.1.10 - - [13/May/2013:16:19:31 +0100] [example.com/sid#7fd764555ed0][rid#7fd764ad9758/initial] (2) prefixed with document_root to /test/test2.html
192.168.1.10 - - [13/May/2013:16:19:31 +0100] [example.com/sid#7fd764555ed0][rid#7fd764ad9758/initial] (1) go-ahead with /test/test2.html [OK]
```

".htaccess file"

```
# cat /test/.htaccess 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/test.html$ /test2.html
```

Rewrite Log:

```
192.168.1.10 - - [13/May/2013:16:22:17 +0100] [example.com/sid#7fd76455b7d0][rid#7fd764af0d78/initial] (3) [perdir /test/] strip per-dir prefix: /test/test.html -> test.html
192.168.1.10 - - [13/May/2013:16:22:17 +0100] [example.com/sid#7fd76455b7d0][rid#7fd764af0d78/initial] (3) [perdir /test/] applying pattern '^/test.html$' to uri 'test.html'
192.168.1.10 - - [13/May/2013:16:22:17 +0100] [example.com/sid#7fd76455b7d0][rid#7fd764af0d78/initial] (1) [perdir /test/] pass through /test/test.html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the second log, it's looking for "^/test.html$" in "test.html" URL. Cannot match it because of forward slash in pattern.
Try

```
RewriteRule ^test.html$ /test2.html
```

instead of

```
RewriteRule ^/test.html$ /test2.html
```

in your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

Add this above the RewriteRule in your .htaccess:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?/test/test.html$

Change the path to suit your environment.